# Meta tags in shortcode

Tags: shortcode, post-meta

The thumbnail and title shows up as it should, but the post meta displays on the top of the page. What is the correct code for retrieve the post metadata?

```
function evasmat_posts_shortcode(){
    $q = new WP_Query(
        array( 'orderby' => 'date', 'posts_per_page' => '4')
    );

    $list = '<div class="cards">';

    while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();

        $list .= '<div class="card">' .  get_the_post_thumbnail() . '<h2 class="entry-title-index"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title() .'</a></h2>'  .'<div class="entry-meta">' . get_post_meta (evasmat_posted_on() ) .'</div></div>';


    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();

    return $list . '</div>';

}

add_shortcode('recent-posts', 'evasmat_posts_shortcode');
```

Comment: `evasmat_posted_on()` is a function in your theme? Or is it custom post meta data?

Comment: It is a function in my theme.

Comment: please post the full code of that function. does the function return or echo the result?

Answer (score 1):

Since `evasmat_posted_on()` is a function in your theme, you don't need to use `get_post_meta` to get the date. You can call the function directly so:

```
function evasmat_posts_shortcode(){
    $q = new WP_Query(
        array( 'orderby' => 'date', 'posts_per_page' => '4')
    );

    $list = '<div class="cards">';

    while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();

        $list .= '<div class="card">' .  get_the_post_thumbnail() . '<h2 class="entry-title-index"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title() .'</a></h2>'  .'<div class="entry-meta">' . evasmat_posted_on() .'</div></div>';


    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();

    return $list . '</div>';

}

add_shortcode('recent-posts', 'evasmat_posts_shortcode');
```